# stages for developing NFC applications

Tags: android, nfc

i am new to the NFC technology. i have experience in developing Android appllicaions. i need to get some basic concepts regarding the development of NFC applications. to start with, what are steps for developing NFC applications in a mobile phone? i came across to these stages... 1) NFC Chip design (hardware part), 2) software application development, 3)embedded firmware development, 4) Mobile device application development (Java, Android, Windows Mobile etc.). i cannot get any in-depth idea about these. which of the above points are available in the market for free?

as the first step, i just want to develop an API for a NFC enabled android phone. what are the points i need to consider? which SDK?

later, i would like to design hardware and embed it in a mobile and then develop API.

i have come across some APIs like... Google API, Open NFC API, contactless communication API. i dont know what are differences...
i would like to have a clear concept regarding the stages of NFC application development from scratch.

i also want to know about developing APIs in Symbian and iPhone...

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.slideshare.net/tdelazzari/architecture-and-development-of-nfc-applications

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the Open NFC Add-on to eclipse:
http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/

To develop and Android Application use the NFC API:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html